# Java, Level Editor Issue

Tags: java, game-engine, tiles-game

i have ran into a quick problem which i do not know how to do it by myself but i'm sure with your help i will understand more.

I've created a level editor for the game engine i am creating and i am trying to make the mouse position snap to a 32x32(grid) or 64x64(grid) so that the tiles are placed correctly and not overlapping each other.

So that its not like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL60U.jpg
but more like this :
[http://imgur.com/a/nck9N](https://imgur.com/a/nck9N)
Sorry for the really bad explanation.

The mouse position code i am using is

```
public int getMouseX() {
    return mouseX; // Get MouseX
}


public int getMouseY() {
    return mouseY; // Get Mouse Y
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = (int)(e.getX() / gc.getScale() /*+  gc.getWindow().getFrame().get*/);
    mouseY = (int)(e.getY() / gc.getScale()); //CODE TO GET MOUSE X AND Y


}
```

//Code Which Loads the texture/image where the mouse is

```
tMouseX = gc.getInput().getMouseX() -32;
tMouseY = gc.getInput().getMouseY() - 32;
putImage((int)tMouseX,(int)tMouseY,r);
```

//putImage Function

```
public void putImage(int x, int y)
{
    objects.add(new Grass(x,y));

}
```

Trying to make the images snap to 32x32

Comment: Did you write any code for the snapping you want to achieve?

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a clear question -- what problems are you having? What is broken?

Comment: Added some pictures and @luk2302 i do not know how to code this snapping.

Comment: So the question is "how to snap to grid"? Please post a small [mcve] program so we have code that we can work with. This is not your whole program nor code snippets but a small representational new program that is small enough to post here as code-formatted text, and that will compile and run for us without modification.

Comment: Yes its how to snap to grid and ill try to post a small minimal complete and verifiable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about snapping the mouse to the grid, you don't really want to do that.  What you want is to snap the *tile* to the grid.

The best way to do this is with integer division.  Divide by your tile size using integers to truncate the remainder (or use `floor`) and then scale back up by multiplying by your tile size.

```
int tilepos_x = (int)(mousex / tileSize) * tileSize;
int tilepos_y = (int)(mousey / tileSize) * tileSize;
```

Comment: If you need to center the tile, just subtract tileSize/2 from the (x,y) when placing.